# Find all Skype conversations in containing a username and a given text?

Tags: skype, logging, history

I cannot find Skype conversation history `search feature` via Skype itself. This is inconvinient for me when I since I often chat with one customer in serval groups and cannot remember important information mentioned in some of those talks.

I you know a way to, it would be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Skype used sqlite as storage. It is possible to operate on this file by external tools. But I don't know which.

Skype allow group conversation and saving/renaming groups in contact list: https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA1005/how-do-i-start-a-group-instant-message-in-skype-for-windows-desktop

So we use some group conversations for years and some times you need to find old conversation.

I also miss this feature.